# Rethink DB Query for sub array only

Tags: go, rethinkdb

Lets say I have an object in a table called alerts like

```
{ id:"1"
   history:[ {
            date:"some date"
            hid:"1234"
          },
         { 
          date:"some date"
          hid:"1234"
         }
       ]
  }
 { id:"2"
   history:[ {
            date:"some other date"
            hid:"1235"
          },
         { 
          date:"some date"
          hid:"1234"
         }
       ]
  }
```

I want an array of just the history objects from all alerts. If I use pluck such as

```
r.db("irrelevant").table("alerts").pluck("history")
```

I end up with the whole structure with brackets just no id. like

```
{
  history:[{hid:123,date:"some date"}{hid:123,date:"some date"}]
},
{
  history:[{hid:123,date:"some date"}{hid:123,date:"some date"}]
 }
```

When what I want is

```
[{hid:123,date:"some date"},{hid:123,date:"some date"},{hid:123,date:"some date"},{hid:123,date:"some date"}]
```

I'm specifically doing this in go but if I can find a RethinkDB javascript query I could probably translate it into go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [concatMap](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/concat_map/) command

```
r.db("irrelevant").table("alerts").concatMap(r.row.getField('history'))
```

Comment: @camccar yes of course. Rethinkdb query language is very flexible